# C++: Recursive template argument error

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance

I've got used to code like this in Delphi/Lazarus:

```
type
    TPair<TKey, TValue> = record
        Key:TKey;
        Value:TValue;
    end;
    TAbstractList<T> = class
    end;
    TAbstractPairList<TKey, TValue> = class(TAbstractList<TPair<TKey, TValue>>)
    end;
```

And I thought, that templates in C++ are even more powerful. But...

```
#include <stdio.h>

template <class TKey, class TValue>
struct TPair
{
    TKey Key;
    TValue Value;
};

template <class T>
class TAbstractList
{
    public:
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class TList:public virtual TAbstractList<T>
{
    public:
    virtual void DoSomething() {
        printf("%s", "Implementation!");
    };
};

template <class TKey, class TValue>
class TAbstractPairList:public virtual TAbstractList<TPair<TKey, TValue>>
{

};

template <class TKey, class TValue>
class TPairList:public virtual TAbstractPairList<TKey, TValue>,
                       virtual TList<TPair<TKey, TValue>>
{

};

TAbstractPairList<int, int> *List;

int main()
{
    List = new TPairList<int, int>;
    List->DoSomething();
    delete List;
};
```

This code compiles in online C++ compilers, like https://www.onlinegdb.com, but fails to compile in real one, like Borland C++ Builder.

I.e. this one works:

```
typedef TPair<int, int> TMyPair;
TAbstractList<TMyPair> *List;
```

But this one doesn't:

```
TAbstractList<TPair<int, int>> *List;
```

And I can't put "typedef" somewhere between "template" and "class".

What is wrong with this code? Why recursive template arguments aren't possible in some C++ compilers? Can this problem be solved somehow?

Comment: And what is the error? Maybe it is so old and rustly that it does not parse `>>` correctly? You should try putting an extra space in between.

Comment: If you have a really old C++ compiler, it might see `>>` at the end of the template as an operator. The fix used to be to insert a space `> >`.

Comment: "Expression syntax", followed by "Can't generate template specialization from 'TPair<TKey, TValue>'"

Comment: Oh, yeah, it helped, thx.

Comment: I know, that BC++ 3.1 is obsoleted, but my goal is to learn C++ and therefore to test different programs in different environments. Can somebody tell me, why this code compiles in BC++ 3.1, but confuses this compiler? First of all it complains about TPairList<int, int> being abstract, while it isn't. If I declare dummy procedure in TAbstractList - code compiles, List->DoSomething() executes, but it looks like heap corruption happens shortly after that. "Null pointer assignment" happens at program termination and tests show, that TPairList destructor is never executed.